# iOS memory issue with init in viewDidLoad and release in viewDidUnload

Tags: ios

Are there any potential memory issues with the following code?:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [locationManager release];
    locationManager=nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

I have checked it with Instrument and it says there is memory leaking with above code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should release the locationManager in the dealloc method.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [locationManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

The reason for that is that `viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to get called.

For details see these questions:

[When is UIViewController viewDidUnload called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285932/when-is-uiviewcontroller-viewdidunload-called)

[viewdidunload is not getting called at all!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594410/viewdidunload-is-not-getting-called-at-all)

Comment: You are right... I have checked it with Instrument and there was a memory leaking with above code I posted.. That's why I am asking this question... It seems to work fine with dealloc..

Answer (score 0):

It looks quite well besides:

1. At the beginning of `viewDidLoad` add `[super viewDidLoad];`.
2. At the beginning of `viewWillAppear:` add `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`