# ViewDidUnload is not being called for viewControllers inside UIscrollView

Tags: ios, viewdidunload

I have this hierarchy:

MainViewController -> Sub View Controller -> UIScrollViewController -> Several (4) ViewControllers.

When I get out from the `Sub View Controller` I want that the ViewController inside the `UIScrollView` will call their ViewDidUnload so I will be able close some processes.

What is the right way to achieve that, I have to say that I am targeting iOS 4.1 and above.

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 1):

From the UIViewController class reference:

> On iOS 6, views are never purged and viewWillUnload and viewDidUnload
>   are never called. If your view controller needs to perform specific
>   tasks when memory is low, it should override the
>   didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Answer (score 0):

Behavior is a bit different between iOS 4 and iOS 5. See here for [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594410/viewdidunload-is-not-getting-called-at-all).
Are you explicitly removing the views from the hierarchy?