# Dealloc called after popViewControllerAnimated without calling viewDidUnload

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

Project with ARC. Dealloc method is called immediately after the call popViewControllerAnimated viewDidUnload method with no cause. Because of this, I have many different about this type of crash

---

[image: Crash 1]

[image: Crash 2]

[image: Crash 3]

[image: Crash 4]

and many other similar.

Here is the call stack method dealloc

[image: dealloc call stack]

Have any idea?

Comment: What exactly is the question here? You don't expect a dealloc? Is your view controller being retained by anything else than navigation controller?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are viewDidUnload and dealloc always called when tearing down a UIViewController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768076/are-viewdidunload-and-dealloc-always-called-when-tearing-down-a-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko The issue is that I do not understand how you can be called dealloc without viewDidUnload and whether crashes be associated with this behavior.

Comment: @glebus, do you use iOS6 sdk by any chance?

Comment: glebus, despite what the method name is called, viewDidUnload (if I understand it correctly, correct me if I am wrong) is only called when your app runs into low memory situation, that's when the app start calling viewDidUnload. ViewDidUnload doesn't get called when you pop a view controller but viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear does get called. I was confused at first too.

Comment: Dmitry, I am seeing a problem with SDK 6.0 in creating two instances of a viewController and immediately releasing one (hitting the dealloc method), the stack on the break does not come from my code, it's bizarre... from your comment I wonder if you have seen the same?  Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think that `viewDidUnload` will be called?

As mentioned in [Are viewDidUnload and dealloc always called when tearing down a UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768076/are-viewdidunload-and-dealloc-always-called-when-tearing-down-a-uiviewcontroller) , [When is UIViewController viewDidUnload called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285932/when-is-uiviewcontroller-viewdidunload-called) , [viewdidunload is not getting called at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594410/viewdidunload-is-not-getting-called-at-all) , and many other articles, it is perfectly normal for `viewDidUnload` not to be called.

Why should that cause a crash? You must be doing something wrong.